# Asus ZenBook UX391UA - Trackpad intermittent working

Tags: asus

Just installed Ubuntu 18 on this laptop, and after booting it doesn't work, then if I close the lid and wait for it to enter in sleep mode and open it again, the trackpad works.

Any clue? lol